# Error while deploying rails app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This is the log file!I am new to AWS and when deploying a rails app to elastic bean stalk I am getting the following errors.Can;t find any solution!

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2021/04/04 14:11:01 [crit] 3132#0: *1 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 137.59.228.225, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "quinplus-env-1.eba-3w3vyz3h.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2021/04/04 14:11:01 [crit] 3132#0: *1 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 137.59.228.225, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "quinplus-env-1.eba-3w3vyz3h.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://quinplus-env-1.eba-3w3vyz3h.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2021/04/04 14:18:14 [crit] 3132#0: *6 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 137.59.228.225, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "quinplus-env-1.eba-3w3vyz3h.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2021/04/04 14:18:15 [crit] 3132#0: *6 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 137.59.228.225, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "quinplus-env-1.eba-3w3vyz3h.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://quinplus-env-1.eba-3w3vyz3h.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2021/04/04 14:51:47 [crit] 3132#0: *11 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 137.59.228.225, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "quinplus-env-1.eba-3w3vyz3h.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2021/04/04 14:51:47 [crit] 3132#0: *11 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 137.59.228.225, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "quinplus-env-1.eba-3w3vyz3h.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://quinplus-env-1.eba-3w3vyz3h.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
  Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.16.0) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
  Your Ruby version is 2.5.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Comment: Do you have a custom `puma.rb` or `nginx.conf` config? Can you show your `Gemfile`?

Comment: I was facing issues with AWS Elastic Beanstalk so i decided to deploy my app on EC2 instance!
Thanks for your comment!